# Bitmap font rendering and kerning

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, gdi+, rendering

I am attempting to create a bitmap font renderer, however, I am having problems rendering the actual individual letter placements.

I will obtain the font character information via GetCharABCWidthsFloat and GetTextMetricsW, however, I am unsure how to use the ABC width's properly ... or do I need more information to do this?

I do not want to use FreeType or any other libraries's to do this, I am trying to do this with standard functionality available through C++\Windows.

Without the kerning information, the letters will not appear correct. For example, take a look at "Times new roman" when an "f" and a "t" are placed next to each other. Without the correct letter spacing, they will look too far apart.
algorithm example ---

```
float letterBottomLeftX = 0.0f;
float letterHeight = 1.0f;
float letterWidth = 1.0f;

float scale = 1.0f;
for(U32 c = 0; c < numberOfCharacters; ++c)
{
    fon->GetCharcterInfo(charValue, charInfo);
    //float advancedWith = (charInfo.A * scale) + (charInfo.B * scale) + (charInfo.C * scale);

    letterWidth = charInfo.B * scale;
    letterHeight = textMetrics.Height * scale;

    if(c == 0)
    {
        letterBottomLeftX = -(charInfo.A * scale);
    }


    // vertex placement, beginning at letterBottomLeftX

    // texture placement

    // index placement

    letterBottomLeftX += (charInfo.A + charInfo.B + charInfo.C) * scale;
}
```

Here is an example of what it looks like, you can notice the bad spacing between characters. (Ignore the texture UV's, I am going to fix that after I get the letter placement correct).

http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/4015/njpjp2.png

Comment: Has anyone written a bitmap font renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `KERNINGPAIR` seems pretty straightforward. If both the current character and the following character occur in the table via the `wFirst` and `wSecond` members, add the `iKernAmount` to the number of pixels you advance for the next character.

I would suggest creating a `std::map<std::pair<wchar_t,wchar_t>,int>` with the results from `GetKerningPairs` for quick lookup. You have noticed that `GetKerningPairs` does not return a result for every possible combination of characters. This information is coming from the font itself, and it is up to the font designer to indicate which character pairs are in need of adjustment. It is quite possible for this information to be missing entirely, or to be missing character pairs that seem obvious to you.

Make sure you do `SetMapMode(hdc,MM_TEXT)` before calling any of these functions, since the mapping mode affects the results.

Comment: Inteeresting. Where should "SetMapMode(hdc,MM_TEXT)" by put? This is how I do it, I am not sure if it is making proper use of it though (sorry about the many replies, the formatting here is terrible for replies).

HFONT fnt CreateFont(size,0,0,0,FW_NORMAL,0,0,0,ANSI_CHARSET,OUT_TT_PRECIS,CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,PROOF_QUALITY,FF_DONTCARE,"Times New Roman");

Comment: int nKerningPairs = GetKerningPairs(dc, 0, 0);

Comment: KERNINGPAIR * kerningpairs = new KERNINGPAIR[nKerningPairs];

Comment: GetKerningPairs(dc, nKerningPairs, kerningpairs);

Comment: Also, if I am only suppose to be using information via GetKerningPairs, then should I advance the position for the next character? As you can see, I am advancing it currently via the GetABCWidth's B info.

Answer (score 0):

One common solution is to create a letter pair width table.  So the letters 'Ti' would be placed closer together than say MN.  It's a quick table to make and yields decent to excellent results for the cost.

Comment: Is there a way to get create this table autmatically? It would seem like a hack to just place values in there without querying the information some how. GetKerningPairs will not return information on all pairs, even if they need special placement.

Comment: I'm from the land of embedded game development.  A tool to do this would be ideal, but we've been known to shortcut to get results.  Mostly, I was just giving you an idea of a viable solution.